# Based on what connections between the two novellas in Coetzee's Dusklands is that book considered a novel?

Tags: interpretation, intertextuality, j-m-coetzee, dusklands

In the meta question [How do we deal with tags in composite works such as the Bible?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1511/2191) verbose asked,

> [J. M. Coetzee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._M._Coetzee)'s [*Dusklands*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dusklands) comprises two novellas, *The Vietnam Project* and *The Narrative of Jacobus Coetzee*. These novellas have no characters, situations, or specific settings in common, but share themes. Each can be discussed separately or as part of a larger thematic whole. Should we have three separate tags for *Dusklands* and each of the two novellas? Or should we just have a single [dusklands](/questions/tagged/dusklands) for all of them?

The Wikipedia article about this work introduces it follows:

> *Dusklands* (1974) is the debut novel by J. M. Coetzee, winner of the 2003 Nobel Prize in Literature. The novel consists of two separate stories, "The Vietnam Project" and "The Narrative of Jacobus Coetzee."

We *usually* expect a novel to be a single story. Postmodern literature, of which *Dusklands* seems to be an example, has loosened the definition of "novel". Still, the question remains what commonalities and connections exist between "The Vietnam Project" and "The Narrative of Jacobus Coetzee" for them to be considered a single novel, rather than just two stories that happened to be published in the same volume. Is it just the themes, as verbose says? If yes, what are these themes? If there are other connections, what are they?

Note: this question stands on its own. Its purpose is not to answer the meta question referenced above.